# How do I move forwards and/or backwards in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm trying to get my GameObject to move forwards and backwards, but every time I press <kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>s</kbd>, it won't move at all. For <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd>, they will make the GameObject move.

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {   
        
        if (Input.GetKey("w")) 
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0,  0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("s")) 
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, -forwardForce * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d")) 
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
        
    }

}
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Unity uses a [left-handed](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/Transforms.html) axis system, so the first argument in your vector you've correctly places left/right as the x argiment of your vector, however for forward and backwards you likely want to use the z axis (in / out)

```
 rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

also, good on you for applying forces in fixed update, but do remember to use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` when in fixed update, as regular deltatime might not have the correct values here

If this doesn't help, there can be some issues in capturing input during `fixedUpdate`, best form I believe to be capture input in `update`, and set some flag that will be read in `fixedUpdate` where you apply your physics.

Comment: @GeckoGeek please consider accepting the answer if it helped. [See here for more information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you edit the controls you want in the Input Manager. Go to Edit --> Project Settings --> Input. Then, click on Input Manager. You should be able to edit whatever controls you want for whatever input you want. A screenshot is posted below as to what this screen should look like. [Screenshot of Input Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96IEs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using **forwardForce** on Wrong axis (Y - Axis)(X,Y,Z) to move forward you have to use it on Z - Axis .

> `rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.DeltaTime);`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).